# Что означает звёздочка на гитхабе - на что она виляет?

Tags: github

Что означает звёздочка на гитхабе - на что она виляет?
[image: звёздочка на гитхабе]

Comment: влияет на самооценку программиста

Comment: Это как закладка, чтобы позже можно было посмотреть что вы сохраняли

Comment: «на что **виляет** звёздочка» — весьма экзистенциалистический вопрос.

Answer (score 6):

Выполняет две функции.

1. Позволяет добавить интересующий вас проект себе в избранное (**< USERNAME >/ Your stars**).
2. При глобальном поиске позволяет сортировать по количеству звёзд (**Sort: Most stars**). Чем больше звёзд, тем востребованее проект.

Может ещё есть какие-то возможности, но это точно основные.